# How to properly send a sorted model from my controller to the Laravel API Resource collection?

Tags: laravel, api, resources, laravel-resource

This is my controller:

```
    public function branchesNearby($lat, $lng)
{

    $branches = Branch::all();

    //Calculate distance between each branch and client
    //Radius of earth is 6371 KM so multiply the result with radius of earth 6371*pi/180
    foreach ($branches as $branch){
    $branch['distance'] = sqrt(pow(($branch->lat - $lat), 2) + pow(($branch->lng - $lng), 2)) * 108;
    }

    //Sort by nearest first
    $sortedBranches = $branches->sortBy('distance');

    return BranchResource::collection($sortedBranches);

}
```

You can see i created an extra attribute to calculate distance between user location and the branch location. Then, I sort the branch model by distance. However, The api response that i get is:
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fvXw.png)

You can see it is an object. I don't need the keys "2", "0" and "1". I need to remove this extra wrapping and i need it to be an array of objects like this:
[Correct API but without sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv9hS.png)
Surely, It is sorting which causes it to become an object? I tried many other ways, one of them being:

```
$sortedBranches = $collection->sortBy('distance');
$final = $sortedBranches->values()->toJson();
```

and sending this $final to the resource collection. That gives me the error: " call to a member function first() on string in file api resources". This must be something small but i really need help.

Updating:
I did not post my Resource before, this is how it is:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'shop' => $this->shop->name,
            'shop_image' => asset('api/images/' . $this->shop->image_file),
            'lat' => $this->lat,
            'lng' => $this->lng,
            'shop_logo' => asset('api/images/' . $this->shop->logo_file),
            'distance' => $this->distance . " KM"

        ];
```

The error that i get if i use:

```
$sortedBranches = $branches->sortBy('distance')->values()->all();
   return BranchResource::collection($sortedBranches);
```

is:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6JI7.png)

Update 3:

If i don't call the resource collection and simply output the $sortedBranches like this:

```
return response()->json($sortedBranches, 200);
```

Here, the format of the api response is correct but the data is not correct. This is how it looks:
[$sortedBranches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmMGF.png)

Is there a way i can manipulate $sortedBranches and show the output like with the BranchResource?

Comment: I believe you need to do: `$sortedBranches = $branches->sortBy('distance')->values()->all();` Then your json should look like your second image :) Unless the issue is caused by your last wrapper: `BranchResource::collection($sortedBranches);`. Just give it a go :)

Comment: does distance value also include 'km'? as your controller didn't show km thing. And You are going to sort by the distance which includes "km".

Comment: You should query DB by those values (lat, lng) - not fetching all and then triage some of those.

Comment: @RobBiermann Thanks for this response. I tried this earlier too! That gives me the same error. "Call to a member function first() on string in file api resources".

Comment: @JawadChughtai Allright, is that error pointing to code you have posted, or is it referring to a piece of code you haven't posted yet?

Comment: @SachinKumar I don't have distance in my db. I am just using lat and long values stored in the db for each branch and getting users location coordinates in the get parameters of the api to calculate the distance. I need to return an api with a list of all the branches sorted by distance to the user. I have updated the post and added my branchResource where there is "KM"

Comment: @RobBiermann That error refers to the Resource library generated by Laravel. "...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\CollectsResources.php on line 24"

Comment: I must be doing something silly but i can't seem to get my head around it

Comment: @JawadChughtai Thanks for the update. What if the issue is not in the `sortBy` part, but actually in the `BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches);` You are passing a json into it(which is a string), I could see this causing the error you talk about. What does your `BranchResource` do? Maybe leave it out for a sec to see the direct output of `$sortedBranches`?

Comment: @RobBiermann The BranchResource allows me to manipulate the response and make it exactly like i want. Let me post the direct output of $sortedBranches so that you can see the difference.

Comment: @JawadChughtai Thanks for the update, I think we are getting close. What is the output of `BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches);` ? If it is a collection, then you might need to run `BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches)->values()->all()` at the end.

Comment: You can best test this with the `dd(BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches));` or `dump(BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches);` method btw

Comment: @RobBiermann OMG Thanks a big time! Yes i dd() it and it is a collection. `BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches)->values()->all()` did the trick :')
This is my first real project on laravel and thank you for helping me out, I thought doing `$sortedBranches = $branches->sortBy('distance')->values()->all();` is the same as `BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches)->values()->all()`

Comment: Np, I'll post it as an aswer, with a bit more explaination allright? :)

Comment: @RobBiermann Yesss, mark it as an answer with some more explanation. Would definitely help others too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our troubleshoot, the resulting solution should be:

```
return BranchResource::collection($sortedBranches)->values()->all();
```

When you pass a collection into the collect method of the `BranchResource` class, it re-creates the collection. Laravel sees you are returning an (collection)object directly from your controller, and intervenes by casting it to json( i believe this is default). If the resulting json is not converted the way you want, you need to modify this collection. Therfor we needed to modify the `BranchResource::collection()` collection, not the `$sortedBranches` collection.

Edit:

- Modified collect method into collection;

Comment: Small edit: 
`return BranchResource::collect($sortedBranches)->values()->all();` is actually 
`return BranchResource::collection($sortedBranches)->values()->all();`
My bad for typing it wrong. Thanks @Rob Biermann once again

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I modified the answer :)

Comment: @JawadChughtai Could you upvote/mark answer please ? :D then we are even ;)

Comment: Done. I can't upvote because i have less than 15 reputation but have accepted it as the answer :)